# define multiple labels in javafx at once

Tags: java, label, javafx

I would like to declare multiple labels in javafx all at once, is this possible?

at the moment this is what i type, and i have line 20 to 30 labels!!

```
fajr_Label_ar = new Label();
fajr_Label_eng = new Label();
zuhr_Label_ar = new Label();
zuhr_Label_eng = new Label();
asr_Label_ar = new Label();
asr_Label_eng = new Label();
maghrib_Label_ar = new Label();
maghrib_Label_eng = new Label();
isha_Label_ar = new Label();
isha_Label_eng = new Label();
hadith_Label = new Label();
fajr_hourLeft = new Label();
```

Can I declare something along the line of;

```
label1, label2, label3.... = new Label();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about JavaFX. This question is about Java in general ..
I see some localizations there :  en,ar ... so I would suggest this pattern:

```
Label lbs[];

lbs=new Label[7];

String strings_en[]=new String[]{
"fajr",
"zuhr",
"asr",
"maghrib",
"isha",
"hadith",
"fajr_lefthour"
};

String strings_ar[]=new String[]{
"فجر",
"ظهر",
"عصر",
"مغرب",
"عشاء",
"حديث",
"فجر ساعة لاحقة"
};

String strings[];
//assing lan list
strings=strings_ar; // or strings=strings_en;


        for (int i = 0; i < lbs.length; i++) {
            lbs[i]=new Label(strings[i]);//initializing labels
            //doing what you want here with labels 
            //...

        }
```

It would be better to isolate data from design as you can see we have labels as Label array and data as String array.. and it would be better and better to define the lang set before retrieving data as we have done when assign object array strings to object array Ar or en   .. that would help you to extend/scale/debug your program easily and healthy by adding more labels or languages ..